# Can the word "unsettling" be used in a positive sense?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, connotation

For example, in the phrase:

*John told Mary something unexpected and thoroughly **unsettling** - but in the best way a person can be **unsettled***

Is there something wrong (meaning-wise) with this? Can the words *unsettling* and *unsettled* be used this way? (By the way, I have a slight feeling the second occurrence in particular is a bit off).

The context, in case it's not evident, is John telling Mary something she didn't expect, something John wouldn't normally say, which made her feel very surprised, but in a clearly positive way.

Comment: I think you'd be stretching a point - nobody ever really wants to be "unsettled", which is why your example usage is only remotely credible because you've specifically added the clarification *but in the best way a person can be unsettled*. But for me at least that's nowhere near enough - you'd probably need another whole sentence (or a paragraph or more) explaining how Mary could possibly find "being unsettled" to be a positive experience. Without that, it's just confusing.

Comment: Your sentence expresses more the situation that "Mary" got some very bad news (unsettling news), but it was the best possible version of very bad news - not that the news was in any form positive. So your context is more like - "_John was in a car crash, but he escaped with minor cuts and bruises instead of dying_" type situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your example can use unsettled in a positive way, because it appears to use the definition of unsettled meaning "Nervous or worried"

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsettled

```
Popularity: Bottom 40% of words
Simple Definition of unsettled
: feeling nervous, upset, or worried : not comfortable
: not lived in by people : not inhabited or populated
: not yet finally decided or dealt with
Source: Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary
Examples: unsettled in a sentence

Full Definition of unsettled
:  not settled: as
a (1) :  not calm or tranquil :  disturbed <unsettled political conditions> (2) :  likely to vary widely especially in the near future :  variable <unsettled weather> (3) :  not settled down <unsettled dust>
b (1) :  not decided or determined :  doubtful <an unsettled state of mind> (2) :  not resolved or worked out :  undecided <an unsettled question>
c :  characterized by irregularity <an unsettled life>
d :  not inhabited or populated <unsettled land>
e :  mentally unbalanced
f (1) :  not disposed of according to law <an unsettled estate> (2) :  not paid or discharged <unsettled debts>
```

However, one can imagine situations where someone might *desire or prefer* to be unsettled, in the simple sense of "not settled", eg

*"I was an Air Force kid, and moved constantly.  Some kids would have hated it but I loved my unsettled childhood - I got to see so much more of the world."*

Comment: I believe that last example is using *unsettled* in an ironic sense. In the same way I might claim that I rather enjoyed being *terrified* on a roller coaster.

Comment: In that sense, it sort of means "excited" then, i think.

Comment: *Irony* = *the expression of one's meaning by using language that normally signifies the opposite, typically for humorous or emphatic effect*. In the case of *unsettled* it employs *irony* in a better-than-usual way, since the word can be implied to have the meaning of *not-settled*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the writer is trying to indicate that Mary was suddenly able to appreciate a new perspective. I think *unsettled* suggests an unpleasant emotional state too strongly for this to be a good usage. We might praise a haunted house or scary movie as *unsettling* because in that case we want a taste of the unpleasant.
I would say Mary was probably *delightfully disoriented*.

Answer (score 0):

The words *unsettling* and *unsettled* are the grammatical opposites of *settling* and *settled*. Many words synonymous to *unsettling* have connotations that suggest there is more to being *unsettled* than merely being *uncomfortable* and that there are *positive* states associated with being *unsettled*. In fact, many emotional states could be considered opposite to being *settled*.

Example. When Stravinsky's Rite of Spring premiered in the early 20th century, the crowd was so *agitated* by the poignant dissonance, that **there was a riot**. This *agitation* was certainly *unsettling* and the riotous crowd was certainly *unsettled*. Whether or not the event was a *positive* success, that is a critical question of taste. However, people are still discussing it approximately one century later.

Consider the implications of your sentence if we substitute unsettling  for provocative and unsettled for touched.

> John told Mary something unexpected and thoroughly **provocative** - but in the best way a person can be **touched**.